# Stop a looping GIF icon

Tags: java, image, swing, gif, animated-gif

I am using an animated **GIF** image as icon to button.
But this **GIF** loops without stopping.

How can I play this **GIF** icon animation just once?

Answer (score 1):

When creating an animated GIF, there are options to have it only loop a single time. That is where you need to look for a solution to this problem. Swing itself provides no methodology to change the behavior.